# How to empty text boxes when checkbox is unchecked using javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I want to empty the text boxes using Javascript when the checkbox is unchecked in HTML. Here is my code:

```
function sameAddress(){
    var bstreetAddress = document.getElementById("baddress").value;
    var bsuburb = document.getElementById("bsuburb").value;
    var bstate = document.getElementById("bstate").value;
    var bpostcode = document.getElementById("bpostcode").value;

    var dstreetAddress = document.getElementById("daddress");
    var dsuburb = document.getElementById("dsuburb");
    var dstate = document.getElementById("dstate");
    var dpostcode = document.getElementById("dpostcode");

    var checkBoxStatus = document.getElementById("delAddr").checked;

    if (checkBoxStatus = true){
        dstreetAddress.value = bstreetAddress;
        dsuburb.value = bsuburb;
        dstate.value = bstate;
        dpostcode.value = bpostcode;
        }
    if (checkBoxStatus = false){
        dstreetAddress.value = "";
        dsuburb.value = "";
        dstate.value = "";
        dpostcode.value = "";
    }
}

function init(){
    var checkBox = document.getElementById("delAddr");
    checkBox.onchange = sameAddress;
}

window.onload = init;
```

When I check the box, it is filling the same as desired, but when I uncheck the box, nothing happens at all! Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Don't abuse tags, I have removed `jQuery` tag from your question.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of assigning true or false you must check it whether it is true or false..

```
if (checkBoxStatus == true){
    dstreetAddress.value = bstreetAddress;
    dsuburb.value = bsuburb;
    dstate.value = bstate;
    dpostcode.value = bpostcode;
    }
if (checkBoxStatus == false){
    dstreetAddress.value = "";
    dsuburb.value = "";
    dstate.value = "";
    dpostcode.value = "";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try This

```
if (checkBoxStatus){
        dstreetAddress.value = bstreetAddress;
        dsuburb.value = bsuburb;
        dstate.value = bstate;
        dpostcode.value = bpostcode;
        }
    else {
        dstreetAddress.value = "";
        dsuburb.value = "";
        dstate.value = "";
        dpostcode.value = "";
    }
```

**[DEMO HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/hfTPH/)**

Answer (score 0):

You are assigning it to True of false here:

```
if (checkBoxStatus = true){
    dstreetAddress.value = bstreetAddress;
    dsuburb.value = bsuburb;
    dstate.value = bstate;
    dpostcode.value = bpostcode;
    }
if (checkBoxStatus = false){
    dstreetAddress.value = "";
    dsuburb.value = "";
    dstate.value = "";
    dpostcode.value = "";
}
```

Change it to:

```
if (checkBoxStatus == true){
    dstreetAddress.value = bstreetAddress;
    dsuburb.value = bsuburb;
    dstate.value = bstate;
    dpostcode.value = bpostcode;
    }
if (checkBoxStatus == false){
    dstreetAddress.value = "";
    dsuburb.value = "";
    dstate.value = "";
    dpostcode.value = "";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`if (checkBoxStatus == true){
        dstreetAddress.value = bstreetAddress;
        dsuburb.value = bsuburb;
        dstate.value = bstate;
        dpostcode.value = bpostcode;
}`

Use == instead of =

In both the if conditions.

Comment: It's working! :) Thanks much!
Can you tell me how to bring back the value of dstate to default as it is a listbox.

Comment: Did it
using: dstate.value = dstate.options[0].selected = true;

Answer (score 0):

Use == instead of = in your code and it should work

Answer (score 0):

Just have a look to the `example on this` [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/XF9e6/).

and you can clear all the textboxes data using this simplest method.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you go wrong when you use '=' , an alternative is either directly check the checkboxstatus in the if clause or use '=='

Can be done either way.

Ex :

**if (checkBoxStatus == true) or if (checkBoxStatus)**
..
..
Followed by your code.
Hope it works!!